# Extracting file names from a list using single line for loop - python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, split, list-comprehension

I am trying to see if I can extract the file names from a os.listdir() output by omitting the '.csv' part in one single line `for` loop. 
for example my list of file names look like this :

`files = ['OPS020.csv','OPS340.csv',OPS230.csv','OPS349.csv']`

Then all i could do was this

```
file_names = [f.split('.') for f in files]
file_names = [f[0] for f in file_names]
```

Is there a more elegant and shorter way to do this ? 
the output i'm expecting is

`file_names : ['OPS020','OPS340','OPS230','OPS349']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, something like this would work.

```
from os import path

files = ['OPS020.csv','OPS340.csv','OPS230.csv','OPS349.csv']
filenames = [path.splitext(x)[0] for x in files]
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.path.html?highlight=os#os.path.splitext)

Comment: Just a quick counter-question. If I have additional info in my file name say the list is now ['OPS020.6.csv','OPS340.7.csv','OPS329.2.csv'] where the single digit between the two periods is a score for that particular file. Then the splitext(x)[0] will pull out only 'OPS020.6' , 'OPS340.7' , 'OPS349.2' . Should I need to use another list comprehension wrapper around the above solution ?

Comment: @lamo_738 Ah, so you want it without these scores? Well, you could do `[path.splitext(path.splitext(x)[0])[0] for x in files]`. But since these numbers are not really file extensions, I would use `[path.splitext(x)[0].split(".")[0] for x in files]`. This would be more self-explanatory, since it would state that you have removed the extension first and then you have taken the first part of whatever has left there

Comment: @lamo_738 actually, given the new goal, there is no need for such complexity. You don't even require the `os.path`, you can just do `[x.split(".")[0] for x in files]`, and it gives out the same result - the parts of the fullnames before the first dot